# What Server Mode should I use for SSAS to learn how to use the product

Tags: ssas

I'm installing SSAS 2019 to learn about SSAS.  What server mode should I install SSAS in to learn about using the product?  I'm experienced in SQL Server development.  Online information seems to assume you already have chosen a mode to use.  For example suppose I'm creating a data warehouse and cubes.

I have spotted an [article comparing tabular and multi-dimensional modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/comparing-tabular-and-multidimensional-solutions-ssas?view=asallproducts-allversions).  This says the multi-dimensional mode is only available with SSAS, whereas tabular is available on azure and power BI, so that's an argument for the tabular mode.  The article also states that PowerPivot mode isn't the recommended mode for sharepoint anymore, because power bi is recommended there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on your goals. Multidimensional SSAS models are on the market since 2000 and it gradually becoming a legacy, Microsoft spends little or no efforts extending its functionality. Still it is quite capable BI platform. However, I would invest my time in learning multidimensional SSAS if planning to support some existing projects.
Almost all new SSAS projects nowdays are made on Tabular SSAS, and Power BI is more friendly with Tabular models. So, it will be the recommended choice for new projects.

Answer (score 1):

Just to learn the SSAS I would suggest to learn both. The multidimensional cube / OLAP has a lot concepts that is quite interesting and important for data warehouse. And it is ,for now, still better at dealing with much larger data.

Tabular is more modern and has it core on DAX which is nice. Tabular requires much more RAM if the database size is moderate. Tabular model, in my opinion, is easier to understand at beginning.